# Got error in fread function when building shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I supposed to read file from `fileInput` but when I ran the app I got this error:

> Warning: Error in fread: input= must be a single character string containing a file name, a system command containing at least one space, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or, the input data itself containing at least one \n or \r

My Shiny Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("file","Operation Record",
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      buttonLabel = "Browse...",
                      placeholder = "No file selected",
                      accept = c(
                          "text/csv",
                          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                          ".csv")
            )
        ),
        mainPanel(
            DTOutput("table")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderDT({
        originalDataset <- fread(input = input$file$datapath,encoding = "UTF-8",
                                 select = c("Date","ID","Type","EMail","ClientType"))

        return(originalDataset)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any suggestions?Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the app, `input$file` is `NULL`, until you select a file. You need a `req`:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderDT({
        req(input$file)
        originalDataset <- fread(input = input$file$datapath,encoding = "UTF-8",
                                 select = c("Date","ID","Type","EMail","ClientType"))

        return(originalDataset)
    })
}
```